# How to get firebase 'child( ' ')' automatically?(android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase project data structure is

```
MyPage
FirebaseId
     Food{
         FirebaseID+ random no.
              category:
              id:
              contents:

     Culture
         FirebaseID+ random no.
              category:
              id:
              contents:
```

but I don't know How to get I 'FirebaseID+ random no.' automatically and children.

I use this code, but is not work well.

```
mDatabaseRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MyPage").child(id);
```

Comment: if you want particular id data then you have to enter that id into children and you are able to fetch that data but if you didn't know id and you want to fetch that data then you have to fetch all records and after that you are able to choose one of them.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of your database to see data more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Query for the firebase database but for that you have to know the id of the particular children which data you want for the operation.

```
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = mDatabase.child("Admin").orderByChild("Your Node name" + "/" + Constant.preferences.getString("Your Id", "")).equalTo(true);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                // dataSnapshot is the "issue" node with all children with id 0
                for (DataSnapshot issue : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    // do something with the individual "issues"
                    try {
                         modelclass.add(issue.getValue(ModelClassName.class));
                        Log.e("Get Data", issue.getValue(ModelClassName.class).toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
```